# What am I doing wrong with this requirejs code?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I am trying to learn and use requirejs for a seed application but I can't seem to get the semantics down.

My problem is not the location of the files, that seems to be working fine.

index.html

```
<script data-main="scripts/main.js" src="scripts/lib/require.js"></script>
```

main.js

```
require.config({
    shim: {
        angular: {
            exports: 'angular'
        }
    }
});

require(['app'], function(angular, app) {
    console.info('angular', angular);
    console.info('app', app);
});
```

app.js

```
define(['angular'], function(angular) {
    return angular.module('testApp', [], null);
});
```

console output

> angular  Object {_invokeQueue: Array[0], _runBlocks: Array[0], requires: Array[0], name: "testApp", provider: function…}  main.js:13
>
> app undefined

desired output would have `app` with the contents of the returned module data which seems to currently get assigned to `angular` and `angular` should just be the `angular`global object, something along the lines of

> Object {element: function, bootstrap: function, copy: function, extend: function, equals: function…}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to change my `require()` statement in main.js to

```
require(['app'], function(app) {
    console.info('angular', angular);
    console.info('app', app);
});
```

I removed the `angular` argument so that the reference to angular would be the global object and I see now that the parameters are assigned values in the same order that they are required, unlike how angular uses dependency injection.